# can't override name resolution for firefox on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, dns, hosts-file

I need to override the name resolution for a given domain name for testing purposes in my browser (Firefox) on Ubuntu, so that when I write "www.agivendomain.org", it will point to a given IP that I decide, instead of resolving via DNS.

I already tried editing the /etc/hosts file, but it doesn't work. It does work when I ping the domain from the terminal, but Firefox seems to ignore it. I also flushed and disabled Firefox's DNS cache with no luck. It seems Firefox simply does not look at /etc/hosts and always resolves the domain name by asking the DNS.

What am I missing?

I've found similar questions like "how do I override DNS in Firefox" to which the usual answer is "use /etc/hosts", then the poster usually replies "I don't want to use /etc/hosts for this or that reason" - well I would be perfectly fine with using /etc/hosts but what nobody says is it just doesn't work for Firefox...

Thanks
m.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your hosts file with [pastie](http://pastie.org)?

Comment: My problem seems to be related to some sort of DNS cache. After rebooting, the changes I had made to /etc/hosts finally took effect on Firefox and other browsers.

Comment: Now I've changed /etc/hosts again and the browsers still "uses" the previous version. Now even after rebooting I cannot get the browser to see the changes I've made to /etc/hosts.

Comment: Note that the issue affects all browsers, not only firefox, but not other programs: ping and wget always resolve names correctly according to /etc/hosts.

Comment: I have already tried /etc/init.d/dns-clean, I've already tried disabling dns cache in Firefox both with the DNS Cache addon and manually in about:config. No way.

Comment: There seems to be some dns cache somewhere that only affects browsers and that I can't get rid of. And that occasionally flushes on reboot but not always...... This is very misterious

Comment: @emb1995 here it is: http://pastie.org/2004992

Comment: I've replaced the relevant ip with 99.99.99.99, and the relevant domain with mydomain.net in the pastied version

Comment: Mmm... Make sure you are running the latest version of Firefox. That doesn't seem to be an OS issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a post at [azcentral](http://yourbusiness.azcentral.com/bypass-dns-firefox-9137.html). It says you need to enter two keys in about:config, namely

1. "network.dnsCacheExpiration"
2. "network.dnsCacheEntries"

and set them to 0.

Give it a try. I have not, but your question seems still unanswered.